# How to generate ID with specific letter and adding on number in PHP?

Tags: php

As question.

I need to generate a few case id when I insert into database tables
case id examples: `PR000001`

Letter distribution: -
 - PR=Projector
 
 - TV=Television
 - PC=Personal Computer
Numbering: Add 1 each time I insert into database table.

But I'm confused in how to  get newest case id from database table and add 1 being generate a new relative case id.

---

Simple to say:

Projector newest case id = `PR001` 
Projector generated newest case id = `PR002`

Television newest case id = `TV003`
Television generated newset case id = `TV004`

How to realize it?
I have tried for created two columns but it become more trouble...

Comment: Doing exactly what you want will only lead to performing two queries and a whole lot of string functions to archive it

Comment: @BobbyAxe so sorry i'm not so understanding...